# Using class functions from a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I have two projects in Visual Studio 2010. One is a simple (win32) .exe project and the other is a DLL project.

In the DLL project i created just has a simple class with just one method in it. I want to get access to this class and method from my EXE application. But i would like to access the class as if it were part of the EXE project it self, like:

```
CTest test = new CTest;
test->TestMethod ( );
```

Is there a way to do this? Like releasing the header files of the DLL and add a reference to the DLL somewhere in the EXE project or something...??

Comment: This may help : [How to export an instantiation of a Standard Template Library (STL) class and a class that contains a data member that is an STL object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958)

Comment: See [.Lib Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx) -- your .dll project generates a .lib file, and your .exe project needs to link to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with the advice given by @Luchian Grigore, you need to correctly use `_declspec(dllimport)` and `_declspec(dllexport)` on the class you want to load from a DLL.

Use dllexport when compiling the DLL and dllimport when compiling the executable that uses the DLL.

--- CTest.h ---

```
#ifdef CTEST_EXPORT  // You are compiling the DLL
#define CTEST_DLL_EXPORT _declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define CTEST_DLL_EXPORT _declspec( dllimport )
#endif

class CTEST_DLL_EXPORT CTest
{
public:
    bool TestMethod();
};
```

--- CTest.cpp ---

```
#define CTEST_EXPORT 
bool CTest::TestMethod()
{
    return( true ); // Success?
}
```

--- main.cpp ---

```
#include <iostream.h>  // Whatever cin/cout are declared in...
#include "CTest.h"

int main()
{
    CTest ct;

    if( ct.TestMethod() )
    {
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }
    return( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You include the header and add to extra include libraries the `.lib` generated by the project that also generates the `.dll`.